# My question is not "off-topic"

Tags: support, off-topic

Here is my question: [Fiber attachment mess in LAB](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/72278/49524)

Mainly, I was wondering whether it is possible to reduce cabling complexity in a LAB or not. And what professionals do about this? No specific vendor or product mentioned or requested.
Comments are clear answers to my question.
Reopen it, please!

Answer (score 2):

The first line in your post is:

> Is there any programmable or configurable box that does "switching" at
> the physical level?

That is either a question seeking a Yes/No answer, which is a bad question, or you are asking for a product. Questions like that really are not suitable for SE sites (other than [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)).

Your other question is:

> What do vendors, like Cisco, Arista, and so on, do in their LABs to
> decrease physical intervention for changing topology?

That is something you would need to ask each company because each can do it differently. We really cannot speak for other companies.

---

(I can tell you in my personal experience with our company traveling to Cisco for testing, the Cisco engineers are very disciplined and manually make changes. They rack the test devices and use the cable management attached to the racks. There is no cable mess because they take the time to do it right in the lab.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I applied your concerns and edited my post.

Comment: After editing my post, I don't know to open a new question for reopening it or not. should I?